# How to know Bluetooth Chipset on Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth

I need to know the name of the bluetooth chipset of my device programmatically and I don't know how. I 've searched for it and always I found how to see  CPU information or something like it but not just the bluetooth chipset that is what I'm searching for. Thanks for help!